# О количестве буферов в vulkan

Tags: c++, vulkan

На данный момент я учу вулкан, но уже есть представление о том как это работает. И так, в примере используется vkCmdBindVertexBuffers для того чтобы задать буферы на отрисовку, как я понимаю. Так вот, вопрос про количество буферов: есть ли ограничение на их количество (если мы знаем что памяти физически хватит)?, оно должно стремится к условно одному буферу или есть какие то количество до которого вполне нормально, а потом уже слишком? Или я вообще все надумал и разные буферы можно "неограниченно" использовать для удобства?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать какое угодно кол-во буферов, но вот кол-во аллокаций ограничено.